# Trying to create a cron to Rsync then tar the folder

Tags: shell-script, cron, rsync

I'm stuck at the first hurdle!

I want to run a couple of commands from a bash script. First something like this to rsync some directories:

```
rsync -e ssh -az user-whatever@website.com:/home /location/of/local/folder
```

Then something like this to tar and copy the files somewhere else:

```
cd /location/of/local/folder
tar zcf /var/backups/home-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz home
```

I hope this is making sense.

The problem is that obviously I wish for the rsync to finish before the directory is tar'd. So is there a bit of code I can use to make sure that rsync has finished before running the `tar` command?

e.g. (pseudo code)

```
rsync
while(is syncing){
    sleep 10
}
tar
```

Or will my `.sh` script only run the next line after the first line has finished and exited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands in a shell script are executed sequentially. If your first command is `rsync`, the next command will not execute until `rsync` completes.

What you want to be sure of is that `rsync` finishes successfully before continuing to the next command.

This is not the most elegant solution, but the easiest to implement.

```
rsync -e ssh -az user-whatever@website.com:/home /location/of/local/folder &&\
tar zcf /var/backups/home-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz /location/of/local/folder
```

Keep in mind this will only work if the exit status of `rsync` is `0`. Any other exit status and command 2 will not run.

```
AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the &&
and  ||  control operators, respectively.  AND and OR lists are executed 
with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
    command1 && command2
command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
```

You could add more intelligence to your script if you performed different actions based on the `rsync` EXIT VALUES.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

rsync -e ssh -az user-whatever@website.com:/home /location/of/local/folder

if [ $? != "0" ]
  then
   echo "There was a problem"
  else
   tar zcf /var/backups/home-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz /location/of/local/folder
 fi
```

Comment: This is a brilliant and insightful answer. Thank you very much for taking the time. :) You've really helped me. Thank you.